# postgres error: a negative number raised to a non-integer power yields a complex result

Tags: sql, postgresql

The given query works perfectly fine when executed with DataGrip, but returns the following error when it's submitted by lib/pq:

`pq: a negative number raised to a non-integer power yields a complex result`

The error is happening within postgres as it shows up in the logs

```
SELECT upvotes / (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp-created_at)/3600)^1.8 as score, title,
FROM ideas
ORDER BY score desc
```

simplified schema

```
create table ideas
(
   title text not null,
   created_at timestamp not null,
   upvotes integer default 0 not null
)
```

I'm running postgres v9.2

I'd be very happy about a little hint in where to look into, as I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Check which `created_at` values are in the future.

Comment: yeah, just resolved it, was indeed the issue, thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you've got some timestamps in the future somehow. you can protect the query to ensure that there's no negative results using GREATEST

```
SELECT upvotes / (GREATEST(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp-created_at)/3600),0)^1.8 as score, title,
FROM ideas
ORDER BY score desc
```

Alternatively you can exclude the bad data using a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT upvotes / (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp-created_at)/3600)^1.8 as score, title,
FROM ideas
WHERE current_timestampn >= created_at
ORDER BY score desc
```

Comment: cheers! there was indeed a future timestamp in one of the rows